# Deleting data from one table if the reference doesn't exist in two other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I managed to import too much data into one of my database tables. I want to delete most of this data, but I need to ensure that the reference doesn't exist in either of two other tables before I delete it.

I figured this query would be the solution. It give me the right result on a test database, but in the production environment it returns no hits.

```
select product 
from products
where 1=1
  and product not in (select product from location)
  and product not in (select product from lines)
```

Comment: My query was fine. The problem was that i had one row in [lines] that was missing the product reference. The suggestions below made me understand this. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting no results/hits it means that you table location and/or lines having the null values in the product column. in clause failed if column having null value.

***try below query just added the null condition on the top of your shared query.***

```
select product from products
where 1=1
and product not in ( select product from location where product  is not null)
and product not in ( select product from lines where product  is not null)
```

Comment: I had one row that was missing product in [lines]. You query gave me the right result. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXISTS` instead of `IN` which is more efficient

```
DELETE FROM products WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT
                1
                FROM [Location]
                    WHERE Product = Products.Product
        ) AND
    NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT
                1
                FROM lines
                    WHERE Product = Products.Product
        )
```

Comment: I had one row that was missing product in [lines]. You query gave me the right result though. Seems the Exists dont care about that? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
DELETE FROM Products where not exists 
(select 1 from Location 
join lines on lines.Product = Location.Product 
and Location.Product = Products.Product
);
```

Comment: this is not a right approach, suppose there is a record which does not exist in Location but has an entry in the Lines? so according to your query that record will be deleted, which actually needs to be retained

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh Here Iam using inner join not (left join or right join) so as per your scenario It will be retained..  To delete the records the product should not be in both tables

Comment: He wants to delete records that do not exist in Both the tables, So if you use an Inner Join, then even the record is present in one table, It will be deleted

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell from your post why the query would return results in the test database but not production other than there is different data or different structures.  You might try including the DDL for the participating tables in your post so that we know what the table structures are.  For example, is the "product" column a PK or a text name?

One thing that does jump out is that your query will probably perform poorly.  Try something like this instead:  (Assuming the "product" column is a PK in Products and FK in the other tables.)

```
Select  product
From Products As p
  Left Outer Join Location As l
    On p.product = l.product
    And l.product is null
  Left Outer Join Lines as li
    On p.product = li.product
    And li.product is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple set based approach may help ...

```
DELETE p 
FROM  products p
LEFT JOIN location lo ON p.product = lo.product
LEFT JOIN lines li ON p.product = li.product
WHERE lo.product IS NULL AND li.product IS NULL
```